# ICACLS Setowner to folders only

Tags: windows, ownership, icacls

I need to give `user_foo` full control in all files and subdirectories in a \directory.

`user_foo` is the owner of the /directory.
`user_foo` has own some subdirectories but not all subdirectories.

`icacls \directory /grant user_foo:(OI)(CI)F /T /C`

I believe, (please, confirm me), I have to get ownership of all subdirectories first.

`icacls \directory /setowner user_foo /t /c`

However, I don't want to get ownership of files. Folders must enough. /t parameter affects all the files under \directory.

Any help is appreciated.

PS. All existing permissions should remain.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be owner of folders to be able to grant permissions. You do need to have fullcontrol permissons on the folder yourself of course.

```
icacls \directory /grant user_foo:(OI)(CI)(F)
```